# Compare a users input list to a set list in order with duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, compare

I am trying to take a set of answers either 'A' 'B' 'C' or 'D' in a specific order such as a multiple choice test and have the user input his answers.  After I would like it to create a third list and print out what was right and wrong.  Here is what I have so far.

```
 userAnswersList = []
 correctAnswers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']

 while len(userAnswersList) <= 19:
     userAnswers = input('Give me each answer total of 20 questions I\'ll let  you know how many you missed.')
     userAnswersList.append(userAnswers.upper())

correctedList = []
for i in userAnswersList:
    if i in correctAnswers:
        correctedList.append(i)
    else:
        correctedList.append('XX')

print(correctedList)
```

So my end result would be the corrected list with a 'X' in place where they missed the answer, If it is right it just puts the user input in that place.
So after the user input their 20 answers it would look like
['A', 'C', 'A', 'XX', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'XX', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'XX', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'XX', 'B', 'B', 'XX', 'A']
if they missed 5 questions in that order

***EDIT***

Thank you again for all your help I was able to solve my problems with your help and some great answers. I used Nicks solution as that is how we are learning it.

I will try out others just so I can get used to them.

Comment: search for enumerate a list and then use the index in userAnswersList to compare the result with correctAnswers at this index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using:

```
for i in userAnswersList:
```

you may find it easier to iterate through the array and check if the values are equal, such as:

```
for i in range(len(userAnswersList)):
    if userAnswersList[i] == correctAnswers[i]:
        correctedList.append(userAnswersList[i])
    else:
        correctedList.append('XX')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no question here, so I'll assume you're asking what's wrong with what you have.

The compare section uses the same variable i in both lists but even if it was different it wouldn't work.

You'll need something along the following lines:

```
for i in range(len(correctAnswers)):
    correctedList.append(correctAnswers[i] if userAnswersList[i] == correctAnswers[i] else 'XX')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python's map method.

As explained in the help for map:

```
map(...)
    map(function, sequence[, sequence, ...]) -> list

    Return a list of the results of applying the function to the items of
    the argument sequence(s).  If more than one sequence is given, the
    function is called with an argument list consisting of the corresponding
    item of each sequence, substituting None for missing values when not all
    sequences have the same length.  If the function is None, return a list of
    the items of the sequence (or a list of tuples if more than one sequence).
```

So in that case, you want to compare each item of your two equal lists, and apply a condition against them. The condition we will introduce will follow this logic:

*if something in one list is not equal to the other, set 'XX', otherwise return the value.*

So, we will introduce what is called a "lambda" function here to put that above condition. Here is documentation on what a lambda is: http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

```
lambda x, y: 'XX' if x != y else y
```

So, when we put it all together, we have this:

```
d = map(lambda x, y: 'XX' if x != y else y, userAnswersList, correctAnswers)
```

Demo:

```
correctAnswers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']
```

---

```
userAnswersList = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'B']
```

Result:

```
['A', 'C', 'A', 'XX', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'XX', 'B', 'A', 'XX', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'XX', 'XX', 'D', 'XX']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together and check the elements at common indexes, you can get all the answers using a *list comprehension* replacing your while with [range](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
userAnswersList = [input('Give me each answer total of 20 questions I\'ll let  you know how many you missed.').upper() 
                   for _ in range(20)]
correctAnswers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']

correctedList = ["XX" if u_a != c_a else u_a for u_a, c_a in zip(userAnswersList)]
```

If the corresponding elements from each list are the same we add the letter, if not we add `"XX"` to mark an incorrect answer.

Comment: Would map work here as well? I just put together a solution as well using map. Curious to know your take on it.

Comment: @idjaw, it would work but I  think zip would be the idiomatic approach.